# Simultaneous pressing of keys in safari using webdriver?

Tags: selenium, safari, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I'm trying to test a keyboard shortcut on mac safari using webdriver (c# V2.39.0), the shortcut involves pressing a key whilst another key is pressed.

This is easy to do using the actions api but this is not supported for safari. Is there any other way I can test this? I've had a look at the Javascrip executor but I didn't get very far.

Thanks